# Pitfalls of creating a foreign key constraint on a system table?

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, foreign-key

I have a number of tables which hold metadata about the tables and packages in the system. This is intended to be a resource for analysts and documentation so it is not used to create data.

One of the columns that appears in a few of these tables shows the user or "Owner" of the object.  The data should only contain user accounts in the database and it seems like a good practice to have a foreign key constraint from the metadata tables to  sys.user$.

However I have always approached SYS tables with caution and I was surprised to see that there is no primary key for SYS.USER$ only a unique index on the NAME column.

As far as I know I cannot create a foreign key on sys.all_users.  Or I could create a table as Select username, user_id from all_users  so the data entry is checked on insert but it all seems very clumsy.

Is there a better way to access a table that has a primary key and the names of all schemas?

I ended up adding a check constraint as a hard coded solution that won't mess with system files.  I still think there should be way to get a list of the schemas or "owners" that can be used as a foreign key constraint.

@Phil, why don't you post your comment as an answer?

Comment: Use a trigger or something in the app code to do the verification against the all_users view. Never ever ever ever mess with anything that's deemed "internal". No extra indexes, no foreign keys etc. Erase the possibilities from your mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not find an elegant way to solve this question but adding a check constraint on the "Owner" column of the metadata tables accomplished the objective of ensuring that only schema owners would be listed.  If a new schema owner is added then all the check constraints would have to be changed but that is not too onerous.

I tip my hat to Phil for confirming that backing away slowly from system tables is the best approach and wish he had posted this as an answer.

Comment: @Phil  please submit your comment as an answer and I'll do so